# Setting up a compose scaffold with NavHost at higher level

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am trying to setup an application flow in which there is a main route/screen, followed by a home route/screen where the home screen contains a scaffold to setup bottom bar navigation.

I originally had the scaffold setup at the main (top level) route where the scaffold content was just the NavHost ie:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
   val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
   val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
   val bottomSheetNavigator = rememberBottomSheetNavigator()
   val navController = rememberNavController(bottomSheetNavigator)

   ModalBottomSheetLayout(bottomSheetNavigator) {
      Scaffold(
         scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
         drawerGesturesEnabled = false,
         drawerContent = {...},
         bottomBar = {...}
      ) {
         NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = "tab1"
         ) {
            tab1Graph(navController)
            tab2Graph(navController)
            tab3Graph(navController)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Which is fine I suppose, however since only my home route needs a scaffold, why have the scaffold at the top level instead of at the lower level in which its needed.

Here is my attempt to move the scaffold into the home screen:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.homeGraph(
   navController: NavController,
   bottomSheetNavigator: BottomSheetNavigator
) {
   composable("home") {
         val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
         val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

         ModalBottomSheetLayout(bottomSheetNavigator) {
            Scaffold(
               scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
               drawerContent = {...},
               bottomBar = {...}
            ) {
               // Not entirely sure how to setup bottom nav tabs within the scaffold?
            }
         }
      }
}
```

However I am lost at how to get the tab content to live inside the scaffold based on route.  EG the same magic that happens when you embed the NavHost inside the scaffold.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a project where I solved the same problem.

First, in the MainActivity I call my MainNavGraph, then in the main NavGraph, I call my HomeScreen Composable which contains the BottomNavGraph and the screens to display in this HomeScreen. Finally, in the BottomNavGraph I include everything related to the HomeScreen

MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

        }
        val yourViewModel = viewModel(modelClass = YourViewModel::class.java)

        YourProjectTheme {
            MainNavGraph(yourViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Main navigation

```
@Composable
fun MainNavGraph(
    yourMainViewModel: YourMainViewModel?,
){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    
    NavHost(
        navController = NavController,
        startDestination = "top_level_composable"
    ){
        composable("top_level_composable"){
            TopLevelComposable{
                navController.navigate("home_screen")
            }
        }
    
        composable("home_screen"){
            home()
        }
    }
}
```

Home Screen

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(){
    val homeNavController = rememberNavController()
    val anotherViewModel = viewModel(modelClass = AnotherViewModel::class.java)

    Scaffold(
        ...
        ...
        bottomBar = { BottomNavigationBar(navController) }
        content = { padding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)){
                HomeNavGraph(
                    navController = homeNavController,
                    anotherViewModel = anotherViewModel
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

HomeNavGraph

```
@Composable
fun HomeNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    anotherViewModel: AnotherViewModel
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        route = "home_nav",
        startDestination = "welcome"
    ){
        composable("welcome"){
            WelcomeScreen(navController)
        }
        
        composable("posts"){
            PostsScreen(navController, anotherViewModel)
        }
        
        composable("search"){
            SearchScreen(navController)
        }
        
        composable("messages"){
            MessagesScreen(navController)
        }
        
        composable("profile"){
            ProfileScreen(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

BottomNavigation

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController) {
    val items = listOf(
        "welcome",
        "posts",
        "search",
        "messages",
        "profile",
    )
    BottomNavigation(
        backgroundColor = Color.White,
        contentColor = Color.Black,
        modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 20.dp, topStart = 20.dp)),
    ) {
        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

        items.forEach { item ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                label = { Text(text = item) },
                selectedContentColor = GWpalette.ImperialRed,
                unselectedContentColor = GWpalette.Gunmetal,
                alwaysShowLabel = false,
                selected = currentRoute == item,
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(item) {
                        // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
                        // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
                        // on the back stack as users select items
                        navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { route ->
                            popUpTo(route) {
                                saveState = true
                            }
                        }
                        // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                        // reselecting the same item
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                        restoreState = true
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

You can see how to create Bottom Navigation Bar with Jetpack Compose here
https://johncodeos.com/how-to-create-bottom-navigation-bar-with-jetpack-compose/

Answer (score -1):

You can conditionally use the Scaffold based on the current route:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
val navBackStateEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
if (navBackStateEntry?.destination?.route == "my_route") {
  Scaffold(...)
} else {
  Text("No scaffold")
}
```